# How did the triennial Torah reading fulfil the ordninance Ezra?

Tags: torah-reading, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shavuos, tractate-megillah, curse

Ezra declared that the curses in Vayikra be read before Shavuos and those in Devarim before Rosh HaShana ([Megillah 31b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.31b.10)). How was that accomplished by those in Eretz Yisrael who had a [triennial system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triennial_cycle) for reading the Torah?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They would take out a separate Sefer Torah and read the curses, in addition to the standard weekly parshah.

---

Source: I heard it directly from a well-known rav, who based it on the Rambam Hil. [Tefillah, 13](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920178/jewish/Tefilah-and-Birkat-Kohanim-Chapter-Thirteen.htm):1-2.

Comment: Note that the triennial reading done then is not the same as what is done in Reform and some Conservative shuls. Theirs was "consecutive". The current version follows the annual weekly parsha but does about 1/3 of it. If I have time, I'll put a link to an article that discusses these differences. You just triggered a separate question that I should post.

Comment: I know I saw this somewhere in the Penei Yehoshua or Turei Even or the like, but I can't find it now

Comment: I heard a similar idea about Simchat Torah: They used to read V'zos Habracha then but that doesn't mean that it was a siyum. That custom developed later, even in the one-year cycle. See Tosefos there, that they read a different haftorah in the time of the gemara, one that wasn't so Simchat Torah-dik.

Comment: Sources: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=59875&st=&pgnum=127 https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22600&st=&pgnum=144